# How to create variables dynamically in Java?

Tags: java, string

I need to create new variables `Strings` such that

```
String person1 = "female";
String person2 = "female";
........
........
String person60 = "male";
........
String person100 = "male";
```

This is what I tried

```
for (int i = 1; i <101; i++) {
  if (i<60) {
    String person+i = "female";
  }
  else {
    String person+i = "male";   
  }
}
```

Can anybody help me correct this code?

Comment: Use an array. You cannot name variables dynamically.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ...easily.

Comment: What is your final goal?

Comment: If I had a dollar for every time this type of question were asked here, I'd be a rich man. As an aside, I'd either use a boolean, male, or an enum `Sex {MALE, FEMALE}`

Comment: Use an Array if you know the size, or go for List...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels If you find a question that's close enough to this one, flag (or close vote) this as a duplicate.

Comment: OK @luiscubal: here's one of many duplicates: [dynamic variable names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665655/create-variable-names-using-a-loop-in-java). Voting to close question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A Map allows you to relate any key with any value. In this case, the key is the name of the variable, and the value is the value

```
Map<String, String> details = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 1; i <101; i++) {
    if (i<60) {
        details.put("person" + i, "female");
    }
    else {
        details.put("person" + i, "male");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You are close.  If you store the the gender of each person in an array, you can do it like this:

```
String[] persons = new String[100]
for (int i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
  if (i<60) {
    persons[i] = "female";
  }
  else {
    persons[i] = "male";   
  }
}
```

Alternately, if a person is more than a gender, consider making a class `Person` that holds a gender field, and then have an array of `Person`s.  You would set the gender in a similar way.

Answer (score 6):

You might use a `Map<String,String>` where the key is your "variable name" and the value is the value of that variable.

Answer (score 4):

You will need a `String[]` of some size that you can determine dynamically.
Then, assign values to the array elements.

```
String[] anArray;

// some magic logic

anArray = new String[100];
for(int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++){
 // more magic logic to initialize the elements
}
```

Another option is a `Vector<>` or `ArrayList<>` like so:

```
List<String> anExpandableArray = new ArrayList<String>();
// add String data
anExpandaleArray.add("Foo");
anExpandaleArray.add("Bar");
```

Answer (score 4):

When you find yourself wanting to create "more variables" of the same type, you usually want a list of some kind. There are two fundamental kinds of "lists" in Java: Arrays, and `List`s.

An array:

```
String[] people = new String[10];               // That gives you room for 10

people[0] = "female";
people[1] = "male";
// ...
int n = 1;
System.out.println("Person " + n + " is " + people[n]);
```

A `List`:

```
List<String> people = new LinkedList<String>(); // Expandable
people.add("female");
people.add("male");
// ...
int n = 1;
System.out.println("Person " + n + " is " + people.get(n));
// Note difference -------------------------------^^^^^^^
```

Using an array is great when you know in advance how many there will be. Using a list is great when you don't know how many there will be.

Note on lists: There's an *interface*, `List`, and then there are multiple different concrete implementations of it with different runtime performance characteristics (`LinkedList`, `ArrayList`, and so on). These are in [`java.util`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 3):

Just Use an array like so

```
String[] people = new String[numofelements];
```

And to initialise the array

```
for(int i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
      people[i] = "whatever";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] persons = new String[101];

for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
    if (i < 60) {
       String persons[i] = "female";
    } else {
       String persons[i] = "male";   
    }
}
```