# Dynamic variable declaration in Java

Tags: java

Here I need to create a XML for soap request. It may have multiple userid tags like below.

```
<userid>123</userid>
<userid>456</userid>
...
```

Below is my code to add that tags into XML.

```
SOAPElement userid1 = example.addChildElement("userid");
SOAPElement userid2 = example.addChildElement("userid");
userid1.addTextNode("123");
userid2.addTextNode("456");
```

The above code works for two `userids` but not more then that so below is the java code to add tags and values to XML.

```
for(int i = 0; i < userids.length; i++){
    SOAPElement userid+i = example.addChildElement("userid");
    userid+i.addTextNode(userids[i]);
}
```

Here the issue is `SOAPElement userid+i = example.addChildElement("userid");` is not working.

Comment: you can't change a variables name dynamically. What you can do is use an array or arrayList

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning variables with dynamic names in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729605/assigning-variables-with-dynamic-names-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create variables dynamically in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336202/how-to-create-variables-dynamically-in-java)

Comment: Maybe because if you google this question title the first link is to a duplicate of this question where OP could get the answer. Maybe because OP has shown 0 effort to solve the problem. Maybe because of the extremely detailed problem statement of "_[this line of code] is not working_" I'm trying to figure out why there was ever an upvote.

Comment: userid+i is a rvalue and cannot be assigned any value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SOAPElement[] userid = new SOAPElement[userids.length]
for(int i=0; i<userids.length; i++){
        userid[i] = example.addChildElement("userid");
        userid[i].addTextNode(userids[i]);
    }
```

'userid+i' is not an acceptable java variable name (identifier) so you must be getting a compile time error like *i cannot be resolved to a variable*.

Better approach is to use an array of values, you can use an array of *SOAPElement* objects as I have listed above or other (Like [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html)) Implementations of java Collections

Also read [valid java identifier rules](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Intro/var-ident.html)

Comment: Tried, for loop first line is saying, Can not covert SOAPElement to SOAPElement[].